# How to perform other operations when my tokenizer recognizes a token?

Tags: c++, tokenize

I have written a simple tokenizer that will split a command line into seperate lines each containing a single word. I am trying to ...

- Make the program close if the first word of a command line is "quit"
- Recognize instructions such as "Pickup", "Save", and "Go" in which the compiler will then look to the next token.

My idea has been to use a simple switch with cases to check for these commands, but I cannot figure out where to place it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char command[256];
int commandIndex;
char token[32];

int isWhiteSpace(char character) {
    if (character == ' ') { 
        return 1;
    }
    else if(character == '\t') { 
        return 1; 
    } 
    else if(character < ' ') {
        return 1;
    }
    else { 
        return 0; 
    }
} char* getToken() {
    int index = 0; // Skip white spaces
    while(commandIndex<256 && isWhiteSpace(command[commandIndex])) {
        commandIndex ++;
    } // If at end of line return empty token
    if(commandIndex>=256) {
        token[0] = 0;
        return token;
    } // Capture token
    while(commandIndex<256 && !isWhiteSpace(command[commandIndex])) { 
        token[index] = command[commandIndex];
        index++;
        commandIndex ++;
    }       
    token[index] = 0;
    return token;
} 
void main() {
    printf("Zeta - Version 2.0\n");
    while(1) {
        printf("Command: ");
        gets_s(command);
        commandIndex = 0;
        char* token = getToken();
        while (strcmp(token,"") != 0) {
            printf("%s\n", token);
            token = getToken();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A little reorganization of the loop you have in main will do it.

```
int main() {
    printf("Zeta - Version 2.0\n");
    bool done = false;
    while (!done) {
        printf("Command: ");
        gets_s(command);
        commandIndex = 0;
        char* token = getToken();
        if (strcmp(token, "quit") == 0) {
            done = true;
        } else if (strcmp(token, "pickup") == 0) {
            doPickup();
        } else if (strcmp(token, "save") == 0) {
            char * filename = getToken();
            doSave(filename);
        } ...
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can't use a switch statement with strings, so you just use a bunch of `if ... else if ...` statements to check for each command.  There are other approaches, but this one required the fewest changes from the code you already have.

In the example, under the handling for `"save"` I showed how you can just call `getToken` again to get the next token on the same command line.

(Note that I also fixed the return value for `main`.  Some compilers will let you use `void`, but that's not standard so it's best if you don't do that.)